# After upgrading WildFly, ${app.flag!='N'} in EL suddenly throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N"

Tags: jsf, wildfly, el

We have upgraded wildfly 14 to 26.1.3 recently and we are facing facing an error in one of the jsf 1.2 page where we are using el expression to evaluate Boolean value eg `${app.flag!='N'}`, facing below error while parsing this. could someone help me to resolve this.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:276)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:258)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.equals(ELSupport.java:126)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:36)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:184)
    at com.bally.acsc.custom.components.html.ACSCCustomOutputText.encodeEnd(ACSCCustomOutputText.java:61)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:220)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:215)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.openfaces.ajax.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:64)
    at org.openfaces.ajax.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:413)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at com.bally.acsc.system.CustomFacesServlet.service(CustomFacesServlet.java:70)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.openfaces.util.ResourceFilter.doFilter(ResourceFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.bally.acsc.login.ACSCAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ACSCAuthenticationFilter.java:326)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

i tied excluding the jsf modules from wildfly but no help.

Comment: Your question is genuinely confusing. You said that `${app.flag}` is a `Boolean` but the stack trace says that the runtime interpreted it as a `Long` and you're nonetheless trying to compare it against a `String` of `N`, which is neither `Boolean` nor `Long`. What exactly is it now? You better show the source code of `getFlag()` and/or `isFlag()` method of the class behind `${app}` because everything else depends on that.

Comment: It's very well possible that the EL implementation of the previous runtime had a bug which incorrectly allowed the `${app.flag!='N'}` expression but it *always* evaluated to `true` irrespective of the value of `flag` property. In other words, upgrading WildFly simply uncovered an existing bug in your application.

Comment: app.flag is a "char" type bean property with value either Y or N. Based on the flag it will display false or true in screen. it is working with tomcat and even wildfly 14. found the route cause, its because its invoking el-impl jar from Wildfly module instead of jar which is available in .war file.

Comment: You was indeed relying on a bug. Replace your `char` by `enum` and you should be good to go. See abovelinked duplicate. Or if there are really only two options, use a `boolean` (not `Boolean`!).

Comment: its valid case,  eg: 
<c:if test="#{app.flag!='N'}">
            <h:outputLabel value="Display your text" />
</c:if>
when evaluating the above, im getting the error. Wildfly jar incorrectly converting it to number and throwing error. This is the jar "jakarta.el-3.0.3.jbossorg-4.jar" misbehaving. i want to exclude it from my application dependency. but it seems wildfly implicitly added.